# Google maps Jquery in Wordpress doesn't show anything

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

New to this site and new-ish to Jquery.

Look at my temp site: www.bluelime.be/jibjib, there should be a Googll-e map showing in the header, but it doesn't.
You can check a working template here: http://pentea.cap-tic.com/

The template I'm using is this one: http://preview.ait-themes.com/index.php?bartype=desktop&theme=directory

I already submitted a question to the support theme, but still no answer.

I have the feeling the script is just not running...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors on console ? How did you use `jQuery` ? Is this `$` or `jQuery` ?

Comment: One error but irrelevant to Gmaps
Sorry for my noobness, but what do you mean with $? PHP?

Comment: Did you use `$()` or `jQuery()`, what the error says ?

Comment: If you admit to being a noob, then you should leave the relevance of errors to those you are asking.

Comment: You're right, David  

These are the errors:  

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined jquery.html5placeholder.min.js:12  
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.colorbox-min.js:4  
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js:29  
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'colorbox' 
  
I didn't touch the coding part, but it's with jquery()

Comment: A live link or some code may help us help you

Comment: If you check the source on http://www.bluelime.be/jibjib, look for directory-main-bar:  
'<div id="directory-main-bar" data-category="0" data-location="0" data-search="" data-geolocation="true"></div>'  

I think normally a script must be run at that time.  

Is that enough, or what else can I show you?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all these errors are related to [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

This property has been removed in jQuery 1.9 , so I guess you are using jQuery 1.9 or newer which is not compatible with the used plugin-versions.

Check the plugin-homepages for compatible updates(recommended) or try to use [jquery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dr Molle, however I changed the Google CDN version 2.0 to 1.8.3 and it didn't change anything.  I'd like to try jquery-migrate, I still need to find the way to properly insert it into PHP

Comment: A link to the page would be helpful

Comment: The requested URL /jibjib was not found on this server

Comment: Take a look at the console, there is another error related to `$.autocomplete`, fix this error. When I remove this buggy script the map works fine, so nothing is wrong with the map.

Comment: Cheers @Dr.Molle, now to find the way to remove this like you did